# Mail confirmation issue in ASP.NET Core Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a project which is in ASP.NET Core.

In this project users have to confirm their mail before using their panel. I have written this part of code but there is a problem.

> When I debug project and I get the confirmation link, copy it and
> paste it to browser, mail confirmation goes successful

but

> when I send confirmation Url by email to user's mail and user clicks on it to redirect to my website confirmation fails.

I don't understand the issue because it's weird. I have hard coded some part to test it but nothing changed.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (model.ReferralCode != null)
                    {
                        var tmpUser = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(f => f.IntroductionCode == model.ReferralCode);
                        if(tmpUser == null)
                        {
                            return Json(new { result = "error", target = "register", message = $"No user found with this({model.ReferralCode}) referral code" });
                        }
                    }
                    var user = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        FullName = model.FullName,
                        Email = model.Email,
                        UserName = model.Email,
                        Balance = 0,
                        ReferralCode = model.ReferralCode,
                        IntroductionCode = new Random().RandomString(16),                        
                        IsVerified = false
                    };
                    var signUpResut = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                    if (signUpResut == IdentityResult.Success)
                    {
                        var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                        var emailActivationUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, verifyToken = token });
                        new MailHelper(_logger).SendConfirmationEmail(user.FullName,user.Id, user.Email, token);
                        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, $"User {model.Email} Registered Successfully.");
                        return Json(new { result = "success", target = "register", message = "You have successfully registered. Check your mail to activate account." });
                    }                    
                    return Json(new { result = "error", target = "register", message = "Something went wrong in server side." });
                }
                return Json(new { result = "error", target = "register", message = "Something went wrong in server side." });
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, $"Failed Registeration : {exc.Message}");
                return Json(new { result = "error", target = "register", message = "Something went wrong in server side." });
            }
        }
```

here is mail sender code

```
public bool SendConfirmationEmail(string name, string id, string email, string confirmationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var mailMessage = new MimeMessage();
                mailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("***", "***"));
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(name, email));
                mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
                var configurationUrl = $"https://localhost:44323/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId={id}&verifyToken={confirmationToken}";
                mailMessage.Body = MailBodyMaker($"<a href=\"{configurationUrl}\">Click here</a>", "Click here");

                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtpClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
                    smtpClient.Authenticate("***", "****");
                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                    smtpClient.Disconnect(true);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, $"Email sending finished with exception ${exc.Message}");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The confirmation link looks like below in debug mode

> https://localhost:44323/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=9bb1a751-813b-48d2-a44c-74fd32a2db9a&verifyToken=CfDJ8A%2FFQtr0XBRFinX98FbsJc5LpPXqjstNllYq%2Br7kr6BHFfA7lBINCCoviE0nqJ6EQc1sJ7RW87jNsaR3fEkEbKoOhemFE62GCrTfn9gEizWV99lZhMrLxJPzGm1u6j3x%2FARoBqVuCVpp34ki0OZM%2BEJi31hNbwyowZ4YwoOnKjMqAOdu2bVG46WfXZBRG9AiOaFNTy326ijQmaTVDNSBl8lQR4gBWkmmRAdkcdFfOasLHD24wyUjmqgkOM2yTJ19Dw%3D%3D

and it looks like below in email body

> https://localhost:44323/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=9bb1a751-813b-48d2-a44c-74fd32a2db9a&verifyToken=CfDJ8A/FQtr0XBRFinX98FbsJc5LpPXqjstNllYq+r7kr6BHFfA7lBINCCoviE0nqJ6EQc1sJ7RW87jNsaR3fEkEbKoOhemFE62GCrTfn9gEizWV99lZhMrLxJPzGm1u6j3x/ARoBqVuCVpp34ki0OZM+EJi31hNbwyowZ4YwoOnKjMqAOdu2bVG46WfXZBRG9AiOaFNTy326ijQmaTVDNSBl8lQR4gBWkmmRAdkcdFfOasLHD24wyUjmqgkOM2yTJ19Dw==

Comment: "confirmation fails" - how?

Comment: May be the link is somehow malformed in the email. Have you confirmed that both links (for the same confirmation) are identical?

Comment: when I use usermanager.ConfirmEmailAsync it fails

Comment: @phuzi I have test it and I have doubt about it. When I see url in debug mode it containes %3d char code but in email it converted to `=`

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us both links?

Comment: @phuzi Yes. I did it. Thank you for response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain characters must be escaped in url, and your verification token contains such characters, however you put it as is into your url here:

```
var configurationUrl = $"https://localhost:44323/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId={id}&verifyToken={confirmationToken}";
```

To escape them - use `Uri.EscapeDataString`:

```
var configurationUrl = $"https://localhost:44323/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId={Uri.EscapeDataString(id)}&verifyToken={Uri.EscapeDataString(confirmationToken)}";
```